# UIButton text colour not being set

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that is being created programmatically.

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:20];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0f green:73/255.0f blue:17/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Everything works apart from setting the `textColor`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0f green:73/255.0f blue:17/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:20]];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0f green:73/255.0f blue:17/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```